# How to install X window system for a minimal desktop?

Tags: centos, software-installation, window, x

On a server running CentOS 7, how to make a minimal install of the X window system?

The idea is to build a very minimal desktop that the end-user will use with only one software for backups. No need for an Internet brower or other tools. I already installed Openbox but cannot run it.

The system should run in text mode, unless the user calling `startx`.

I already installed the server component of X: `xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7_4.2.x86_64`

Calling `startx` returns "Command not found".

I tried adding xinit, with `sudo yum install xinit` and also tried `sudo yum install xorg-xinit` but obtained the error "No package (xorg-)xinit available. Error: nothing to do".

I heard about `xauth` but I'm not sure if it is the client component or only for remote desktops through SSH, and also about `xterm` for the GUI terminal.

I know that many users use `yum groupinstall "X Window System"`to install the X system, but it comes with lot of stuff (Gnome, KDE, a.s.o.) that I don't want in the context of a minimal system.

So, which packages do I need for a minimal X window system to work (without desktop stuff) on CentOS/RedHat/Fedora distros and which repositories other than EPEL should I add if any?